# What does "shareholder" mean in the Guy Ritchie's movie "Revolver"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang, phrase-meaning

I sure it doesn't mean "an owner of shares in a company". In translated movie in my native language this word was missed, and I don't understand what does in mean in this situation.
One character asks "How deep did you bury that shareholder?", the second character answers "Deep". The situation is that soon they will meet the person who was in a prison for 7 years because these two guys betrayed him and now he wants to revenge.
Please sorry if this question not for this forum :)[image]

Comment: You have to provide more context for this question to make sense. Why do you think that the word does not have its usual meaning? Owners of company shares can certainly be buried. Have you considered the possibility that it is the verb _bury_ that might not be used literally?

Comment: And consider that "shareholder" may be used metaphorically, eg, to refer to someone who participated in a "heist" and hence is entitled to a "share" of the "take".  Impossible to tell, though, without considerably more context.